# "to suggest an answer for" or "to suggest an answer to"?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Which one is more idiomatic: `*to suggest an answer to a question*` or `*to suggest an answer for a question*`?

> I intend to introduce the question and suggest an answer **to** it.

or

> I intend to introduce the question and suggest an answer **for** it.

Comment: Both are idiomatic, and both sound fine to me in this context.  You could flip a coin.

Answer (score 2):

Using the preposition “to” after “answer” when describing the answer’s purpose is always the safest bet as the usage will never be wrong and usually sounds more natural. The preposition “for” is often used in cases where “answer” is preceded by the indefinite article (“a/an”), like in the examples you mention, so in this case “for” would work just as well.

Since it’s often used when “answer” is preceded by the indefinite article, “for” is often used in cases where the answer is one of many possible ones, e.g. “an answer for world hunger” but again “to” is the safer bet because “an answer to world hunger” works just as well.

Keep in mind that these are all cases where the preposition following “answer” is describing the answer’s purpose, so “to” would never replace “for” in a sentence like “I have an answer for you” because it would totally change the meaning.

Comment: Regarding "the correct choice under prescriptive grammar" could you explain why this is? Your answer and the linked one don't give the basis for  their conclusions.

Comment: I've totally revamped the answer and removed the reference link.

Comment: @user3169 In the mentioned context, for sounds more natural.